# How do I display the columns from a table based on the count of another table without having to add the count in the SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I want to display everything in the OWNER table but based on the number of dogs he has in the DOG table.

```
SELECT o.OwnerId, o.Name, o.Address, o.Contact
FROM OWNER o LEFT JOIN DOG d ON o.OwnerId = d.OwnerId
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, d.DateOfBirth, '05.04.2014') > 2
HAVING COUNT(d.OwnerId) >= 2
```

However when I run this, I get the error Column 'OWNER.OwnerId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Based on similar problems and my understanding, I've read that you need to add in the aggregate function in your SELECT but even when I the error will just move on to the next column which will be Name. That being said, I do not want the count to actually be displayed. Just the columns in the OWNER table.

Comment: You can change the ```HAVING``` to an ```ORDER BY COUNT(d.OwnerId) DESC``` and return what you're looking for.

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT o.OwnerId, o.Name, o.Address, o.Contact
FROM OWNER o LEFT JOIN DOG d ON o.OwnerId = d.OwnerId
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, d.DateOfBirth, '05.04.2014') > 2
GROUP BY o.OwnerId, o.Name, o.Address, o.Contact
HAVING COUNT(d.DogId) >= 2
```